# Is cyclical referencing bad practice?

Tags: c++, entity-framework, cyclic-reference

Say I have three classes: **EntityManager**, **Entity**, and **Component**.

Entity has an array of components (pointers), and each of these components have a field that is a pointer to the encapsulating Entity.

**EntityManager** has an array of entities, and each entity has a pointer to its encapsulating **EntityManager**.

The reason for this design is data reliance. **Components** need access to the encapsulating entity's fields and some components depend on other entity's fields (pointer to entity manager).

Is this "cyclical" design a bad practice? Should I rethink my design?

Comment: It's not necessarily 'bad practice' or 'bad design'. The point is to get the pointer ownerships/references right.

Comment: I don't see a problem with this. I would suggest you put the logic that add/remove reference at the same place. You don't want to end up with an entity that was a manager but the manager not having the entity.

Answer (score 1):

Anything cyclical is only bad in regards to resource shared/locking resources, particular in regards to multithreading.

Besides, it doesn't even look like this is cyclical. It's more of a side by side design, that is of course that to get EntityManager fields, a Component has to go through the Entity. Or, to get a Component, an EntityManager has to go through an Entity.

In terms of design I would worry about what happens if you need to change the fields of an EntityManager that an Entity or Component are dependent on?